# Copying 1 line from a panda dataframe into multiple lines of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas data frames (df1 and df2) with the same columns, and I am trying to copy 1 line from df1 into multiple lines of df2. df2 is a multi-index data frame, with the first index corresponding to the index values of df1, and the second index an integer value.

Here is how they are defined:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['one', 'two', 'three'], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], data=np.random.random((3, 4)))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three'], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
```

And what they look like:

```
In : df1
Out: 
             c1        c2        c3        c4
one    0.158366  0.843546  0.810493  0.925164
two    0.880147  0.464835  0.416196  0.389786
three  0.138132  0.061891  0.320366  0.727997


In : df2
Out: 
          c1   c2   c3   c4
one   0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
two   0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
      2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
three 0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Now here is how I have managed to copy the data from df1 into df2:

```
for index, data in df1.iterrows():
    num = len(df2.loc[index])
    for i in range(num):
        df2.loc[(index, i)] = df1.loc[index]
```

With the result:

```
In : df2
Out: 
                 c1         c2        c3        c4
one   0  0.158366   0.843546  0.810493  0.925164
      1  0.158366   0.843546  0.810493  0.925164
two   0  0.880147   0.464835  0.416196  0.389786
      1  0.880147   0.464835  0.416196  0.389786
      2  0.880147   0.464835  0.416196  0.389786
three 0  0.138132  0.0618906  0.320366  0.727997
```

Any idea how I could do that more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html), what return `DataFrames` in tuples, so add `[1]` for select second one:

```
np.random.seed(23)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=['one', 'two', 'three'], columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], data=np.random.random((3, 4)))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'two', 'three'], [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
```

---

```
print (df1)
             c1        c2        c3        c4
one    0.517298  0.946963  0.765460  0.282396
two    0.221045  0.686222  0.167139  0.392442
three  0.618052  0.411930  0.002465  0.884032


df3 = df2.align(df1, level=0)[1]
print (df3)
               c1        c2        c3        c4
one   0  0.517298  0.946963  0.765460  0.282396
      1  0.517298  0.946963  0.765460  0.282396
two   0  0.221045  0.686222  0.167139  0.392442
      1  0.221045  0.686222  0.167139  0.392442
      2  0.221045  0.686222  0.167139  0.392442
three 0  0.618052  0.411930  0.002465  0.884032
```

Comment: I've never seen `.align()` method before - thank you!